# Point unselection in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, charts, selection, pie-chart, chart.js

I'm using [**the ChartJS library**](http://www.chartjs.org/), and have a custom pie chart [**like in this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9L4DV/3/).

I can select pie's sector but I can't unselect this.

I find the function `clearSelection()` in the documentation, but I don't know how to use this in my case.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You should get an instance of dxPieChart and call a method of this instance like this:

```
$(".chart").dxPieChart('instance').clearSelection();
```

You can call this on some event such as button click.

On the other hand, if your goal is to de-select pie segment when user clicks this segment (which means toggle selection), you could change your click handler:

```
pointClick: function (point) {
    (point.fullState & 2) ? point.clearSelection() : point.select();
}
```

I created this code based on [javascript from this chart demo](http://chartjs.devexpress.com/Demos/VizGallery/#chart/chartsadvancedfeaturesmultipleseriesselection)